# Visual Studio: If I uninstall VS2017 will the platform toolset still be an option in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I installed VS2019 and want to use it due to some bugs still in VS2017 but I don't want the .exe's or .lib's built to change so I left the SDK and ToolSet as it was.  But can I uninstall VS2017 and still use the VS2017 ToolSet or do I need to leave it installed?  I'd just like to save some disk space if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: No.  The build tools are a separate item in the installer.  Doesn't make sense, if you don't change the ToolSet then you just keep those bugs.

Comment: it was the actual vs2017 program itself that would crash and had some other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no (just tried it).

The 2017 build tools x86/x64 will be uninstalled along with MSVS2017. The SDK version will not be uninstalled if you also have MSVS 2019 installed.

It's a simple matter though to just reinstall the build tools through the VS installer.